# Simplest way to make a spiral line go through an arbitrary point?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.beginPath();

let last = 1
let start = 1
let i = 0
let origin = [250, 250]

for (let i2 = 0; i2 < 20; i2++) {
  ctx.ellipse(...origin, start, start, Math.PI / 2 * i, 0, Math.PI / 2);
  i++
  i %= 4
  if (i == 1) origin[1] -= last
  else if (i == 2) origin[0] += last
  else if (i == 3) origin[1] += last
  else if (i == 0) origin[0] -= last;
  [last, start] = [start, start + last]
}
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath()
ctx.lineCap = 'round'
ctx.lineWidth = 7
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineTo(400, 400)
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

What is the simplest way to make the spiral line go through an arbitrary point in the canvas? For example `400x 400y`. I think adjusting the initial `start` and `last` values based on some calculation could work. The only difference between the first code snippet and the second one is the initial `last` and `start` variables. Other solutions that rewrite the entire thing are welcome too.

```js
        const canvas = document.querySelector( 'canvas' );
        const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();

        let last = 0.643
        let start = 0.643
        let i = 0
        let origin = [250,250]

        for (let i2=0; i2<20; i2++) {
            ctx.ellipse(...origin, start, start, Math.PI/2 *i , 0, Math.PI /2);
            i++
            i%=4
            if (i==1) origin[1] -= last
            if (i==2) origin[0] += last
            if (i==3) origin[1] += last
            if (i==0) origin[0] -= last
            ;[last, start] = [start, start + last]
        }
        ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.lineCap = 'round'
    ctx.lineWidth = 7
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineTo(400, 400)
    ctx.stroke()
```

```html
    <canvas width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Since you didn't mention about initial point's constrain, why don't set that arbitrary point is start point

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you want the spiral to intercept the point. There are twp options.

1. Rotate the spiral to intercept point
2. Scale the spiral to intercept point

This answer solves using method 1. Method 2 has some problems as the number of turns can grow exponentially making the rendering very slow if we don't set limits to where the point of intercept can be.

### Not a spiral

The code you provided does not draw a spiral in the mathematical definition but rather is just a set of connected ellipsoids.

This means that there is more than one function that defines a point on these connected curves. To solve for a point will require some complexity as each possible curve must be solved and the solution then vetted to locate the correct curve. On top of that ellipsoids I find to result in some very ugly math.

### A spiral function

If we define the curve as just one function where the spiral radius is defined by the angle, it is then very easy to solve.

The function for the radius can be a simplified polynomial in the form `Ax^P+C` where x is the angle, `P` is the spiralness (for want of a better term), `A` is the scale (again for want of a better term) and `C` is the start angle

`C` is there if you want to make the step angle of the spiral be a set length eg 1 px would be `angle += 1 / (Ax^P+C)` If C is 0 then `1/0` would result in an infinite loop.

### Drawing the spiral

As defined above there are many types of spirals that can be rendered so there should be one that is close to the spiral you have.

Any point on the spiral is found as follows

```
x = cos(angle) * f(angle) + origin.x
y = sin(angle) * f(angle) + origin.y
```

where f is the poly `f(x) = Ax^P+C`

The following function draws a basic linear spiral f(x) = 1*x^1+0.1

```
function drawSpiral(origin) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        const r = i + 0.1; // f(x) = 1*x^1+0.1
        ctx.lineTo(
            Math.cos(i) * r + origin.x,
            Math.sin(i) * r + origin.y
        );
        i += 0.1 
    }
    ctx.stroke(); 
}
```

### Solve to pass though point

To solve for a point we convert the `point` to a polar coordinate relative to the `origin`. See functions `pointDist` , `pointAngle`. We then solve for `Ax^P+C = dist` in terms of `x` (the angle) and `dist` the distance from the `origin`. Then subtract the angle to the point to get the spirals orientation. (NOTE ^ means to power of, rest of answer uses JavaScripts `**`)

To solve an arbitrary polynomial can become rather complex that is why I used the simplified version.

The function `A * x ** P + C = pointDist(point)` needs to be rearranged in terms of `pointDist(point)`.

This gives `x = ((pointDist(point) - C) / A) ** (1 / P)`

And then subtract the polar angle `x = ((pointDist(point)- C) / A) ** (1 / P) - pointAngle(point)` and we have the angle offset so that the spiral will intercept the point.

### Example

A working example in case the above was TLDR or had too much math like jargon.

- The example defines a spiral via the coefficients of the radius function A, C, and P.
- There are 3 example spirals Black, Blue, and Green.
- A spiral is drawn until its radius is greater than the diagonal distance to the canvas corner. The origin is the center of the canvas.
- The point to intercept is set by the mouse position over the page.
- The spirals are only rendered when the mouse position changes.
- The solution for the simplified polynomial is shown in steps in the function `startAngle`.

While I wrote the code I seam to have lost the orientation and thus needed to add 180 deg to the start angle (Math.PI) or the point ends up midway between spiral arms.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0}, mouseOld  = {x : undefined, y : undefined};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => { mouse.x = e.pageX; mouse.y = e.pageY });
requestAnimationFrame(loop);

const TURNS = 4 * Math.PI * 2;    
let origin = {x: canvas.width / 2, y: canvas.height / 2};
scrollTo(0, origin.y - innerHeight / 2);
const maxRadius = (origin.x ** 2 + origin.y ** 2) ** 0.5; // dist from origin to corner
const pointDist = (p1, p2) => Math.hypot(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y);
const pointAngle = (p1, p2) => Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.x);

const radius = (x, spiral) =>  spiral.A * x ** spiral.P + spiral.C;
const startAngle = (origin, point, spiral) => {
    const dist = pointDist(origin, point);
    const ang = pointAngle(origin, point);
    // Da math
    // from radius function A * x ** P  + C 
    // where x is ang
    // A * x ** P + C = dist
    // A * x ** P = dist - C 
    // x ** P = (dist - C) / A 
    // x = ((dist - C) / A) ** (1 / p)
    return ((dist - spiral.C) / spiral.A) ** (1 / spiral.P) - ang;
}
// F for Fibonacci 
const startAngleF = (origin, point, spiral) => {
    const dist = pointDist(origin, point);
    const ang = pointAngle(origin, point);
    return (1 / spiral.P) * Math.log(dist / spiral.A) - ang;
}
const radiusF = (x, spiral) =>  spiral.A * Math.E ** (spiral.P * x);
const spiral = (P, A, C, rFc = radius, aFc = startAngle) => ({P, A, C, rFc, aFc});
const spirals = [
    spiral(2, 1, 0.1), 
    spiral(3, 0.25, 0.1), 
    spiral(0.3063489,0.2972713047, null, radiusF, startAngleF),
    spiral(0.8,4, null, radiusF, startAngleF),
];


function drawSpiral(origin, point, spiral, col) {
    const start = spiral.aFc(origin, point, spiral);
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    let i = 0;
    while (i < TURNS) {
        const r = spiral.rFc(i, spiral);
        const ang = i - start - Math.PI;
        ctx.lineTo(
            Math.cos(ang) * r + origin.x,
            Math.sin(ang) * r + origin.y
        );
        if (r > maxRadius) { break }
        i += 0.1 
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
loop()
function loop() {
    if (mouse.x !== mouseOld.x || mouse.y !== mouseOld.y) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        drawSpiral(origin, mouse, spirals[0], "#FFF");
        drawSpiral(origin, mouse, spirals[1], "#0FF");
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;
        drawSpiral(origin, mouse, spirals[2], "#FF0");
        drawSpiral(origin, mouse, spirals[3], "#AF0");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineWidth = 7;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.stroke(); 
        Object.assign(mouseOld, mouse);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; background: black }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = "500" height = "500"></canvas>
```

### UPDATE

As requested in the comments

I have added the Fibonacci spiral to the example

- The radius function is `radiusF`
- The function to find the start angle to intercept a point is `startAngleF`
- The two new Fibonacci spirals are colored limeGreen and Yellow
- To use the Fibonacci spiral you must include the functions `radiusF` and `startAngleF` when defining the `spiral` eg `spiral(1, 1, 0, radiusF, startAngleF)`

  Note the 3rd argument is not used and is zero in the eg above. as I don't think you will need it

Comment: What would the arguments be for the ```spiral()``` function be for a Fibonacci spiral?

Comment: @je3rdty That spiral is not a polynomial, but a logarithmic spiral and has the function `r = ae^(bx)` where `r` is radius, `b` is growth, `e` is  Euler's number (JS `Math.E`), `x` is angle, and `a` is start radius (same as C in answer). You will need to solve for  `ae**(bx)=pointDist(origin,point)` in terms of `x` which is `x = (1/b) * ln(r/a) - pointDist(origin,point)` Where `ln` is natural log function `Math.log`  Any values for  `a > 0` and `b > 0`  will result in a Fibonacci spiral.

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand anything in your comment.

Comment: @je3rdty It is I that should apologize. Sorry and I have updated the answer to include the  fibonacci spiral in the example. It is basically the same just with a new radius and startAngle function `radiusF` and `startAngleF`